# Screen auto rotates when unlocking

Tags: android

Hi I am trying to save some values in my activity but I'm having a problem when I save it with  onSaveInstanceState and restore with onRestoreInstanceState, I am saving an int years and it saves the first time the screen changes orientation, the spinner repopulates and sets it at the last value , but not when I switch back the orientation again.

My orientation is set to landscape in my manifest, and I have the two save and restore method overridden but it doesn't seem to work, do I need to do something in onPause aswell?

here is my code:

```
    int years;//global variable
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Spinner spinnerYears = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinYears);//Spinner
            final ArrayAdapter <Integer> adapter = new ArrayAdapter <Integer>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item );
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        for(int i=0;i<=100;i++)
        {
           adapter.add(i);
        }
        spinnerYears.setAdapter(adapter);
        years = spinnerYears.getSelectedItemPosition();

   }//onCreate

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

  savedInstanceState.putInt("MyInt", years);


}

@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
  Spinner spinnerYears = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinYears);//Spinner
    final ArrayAdapter <Integer> adapter = new ArrayAdapter <Integer> (this,      android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item );
           adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        for(int i=0;i<=100;i++)
     {
        adapter.add(i);
     }

      spinnerYears.setAdapter(adapter);
      TextView tvYears = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvYears);//spinner Tv
  tvYears.setVisibility(TextView.GONE);


 int myInt = savedInstanceState.getInt("MyInt");
  spinnerYears.setSelection(myInt);//
  Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Restored int"+myInt, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you don't handle the event of changing orientation, so everytime you change orientation, your program (or `Activity`) is re-created, which means the `onCreate()` method is called always; which leads to a result that `onSaveInstanceState()` and `onRestoreInstanceState()` never being called.

It's being explained here in Android Documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ConfigurationChanges

In order to fix this, in `AndroidManifest.xml` , adding this attribute:

```
android:configChanges="orientation"
```

to avoid `Activity` restarted and, well, good luck with that!

Answer (score 1):

In `onRestoreInstanceState()`, you never assign the value back the the variable `years`.  You assign it to an int and then disregard it.  So when `onSaveInstanceState()` is called, `years` hasn't been set yet and it saves that unset value (0).

If you change your `getInt()` line towards the bottom to be:

```
years = savedInstanceState.getInt("MyInt");
spinnerYears.setSelection(years);
```

it should start working.  Good Luck!